# Implementing checkbox header

Tags: php, html

I have a code which retrieves data from db and show it to a table. It is working fine but I want to implement a checkbox as part of the header which would allow me to select/deselect all rows. The header is just being pulled from db comments so I have no idea on how to implement the `checkbox-select/deselect all` header.

Here is my code,

```
    <div>
    <form action="test4.php" method="post"><?php

if(is_array($result)){
    echo '
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Assign</legend>
        <div>Changes will affect selected rows only.</div>
        <table width=auto cellpadding=1px cellspacing=0px border=1 align=center>

            <thead>
            <tr>';      

    // column comment from DB as column header
    foreach($result[0] as $key => $val){
        echo '<th>'.$colcomments[$key].'</th>';
        }
    echo '
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';
    foreach($result as $row => $info){
    echo '
            <tr>';
    foreach($info as $key => $val){
    if($key=='id'){
    echo '
            <td title="'.$colcomments[$key].'">'.$val.'. 
            <input type="checkbox" name="'.$key.'['.$info['id'].']"
            value="'.$val.'" id="rowid_'.$val.'" />
            <label for="rowid_'.$val.'"></label></td>';
         }
    else {
    echo '
            <td title="'.$colcomments[$key].'">
            <input type="text" name="'.$key.'['.$info['id'].']"
            value="'.$val.'" />
            </td>';
         }
         }
    echo '
            </tr>'; 
         }
    echo '
            </tbody>
            </table>
    </fieldset>';
    }
?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select Date</legend>
        <div>Select Date from and Date to</div>
        <input type="date" name="from" id="from" value="<?=$date['from']; ?>" />
        <input type="date" name="to" id="to" value="<?=$date['to']; ?>" />
        <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
```

This is the my script for the checkbox, and I dont know where I can insert a code to create a checkbox header. This is different from the ones posted previously as my issue is how I can create a checkbox header, if i only used the commments section in my db to make it as the header.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery("input[name=checkall]").click(function () {
    jQuery('input[name=checkall]').prop('checked', this.checked);
    jQuery('input[name=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
  });


  // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
  // and viceversa
  jQuery("input[name=checkbox]").click(function(){

    if(jQuery("input[name=checkbox]").length == jQuery("input[name=checkbox]:checked").length) {
        jQuery("input[name=checkall]").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        jQuery("input[name=checkall]").prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: In the body of your table you check if  `key == id` and if so you put a checkbox. Can't you do the same in the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm marking this as resolved. Easy fix is just to set the type to `hidden`.

Change from

```
<input type="checkbox" name="'.$key.'['.$info['id'].']"
```

To

```
<input type="hidden" name="'.$key.'['.$info['id'].']"
```

Checkbox is just a redundant since I need to update all rows anyways.